# Missing sessionDidReceiveChallenge in Alamofire 5 delegate

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire5

I need to migrate from Alamofire 4 to 5 but I'm missing `sessionDidReceiveChallenge` callback on the delegate

I used before in version 4 something like this:

```swift
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
    configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default
)

manager.delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { session, challenge in

    let method = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod

    if method == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate {
        return (.useCredential, self.cert.urlCredential())
    }
    if method == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)
        return (.useCredential, credential)
    }
    return (.performDefaultHandling, Optional.none)
}
```

but now is version 5 the delegate has changed to `SessionDelegate` class without providing a similar function

I tried to use the delegate from the `URLSession` like this:

```swift
let delegate = SomeSessionDelegate()

let delegateQueue: OperationQueue = .init()

delegateQueue.underlyingQueue = .global(qos: .background)

let session = URLSession(
    configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.af.default,
    delegate: delegate,
    delegateQueue: delegateQueue
)

let manager = Alamofire.Session(
    session: session,
    delegate: SessionDelegate(),
    rootQueue: .global(qos: .background)
)

class SomeSessionDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {

    let cert = ...

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        //same impl as before
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that my implementation in version 5 is wrong because I stopped getting response callback

Please advise on how to manage the request challenge properly in version 5

Comment: +1 , were you able to fix it with Alamofire 5 ? If so please add it somewhere for reference, as I'm also facing issue.

Comment: yes I will post what I did in a minute

Comment: @Dhruv if you use `URLProtectionSpace` you wouldn't need the delegate call

Comment: @zombie Did you fixed the issue? If yes then kindly share the code. Thanks!

Comment: I did share the code it's my answer below

Comment: @zombie can you provide a little more detail of how to use URLProtectionSpace instead of sessionDidReceiveChallenge? Thansk!

Comment: @IHSANKHAN I'm not sure what you're struggling with because the answer that I have is self explanatory so if you have a specific question I would be happy to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary to override the `SessionDelegate` to use client certificates. Alamofire will automatically use an attached `URLCredential` for client certificate challenges. Just attach the credential to the request:

```swift
AF.request(...)
    .authenticate(with: clientCertCredential)
    .response...
```

Also, your server trust check will return any trust as valid, which could be a security issue. I'd stop using that code immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion not to accept any certificate but doesn't matter in my case since the whole app is only allowed to connect to one host

Comment: is there a way to add the certificate to the session instead of the single request (other than writing an extension on the request)

Comment: Yes, you can set up the `URLSessionConfiguration` with a custom `URLCredentialStorage` or use the `shared` `URLCredentialStorage`. You can set a default credential for the client cert space.

Answer (score 0):

For a certificate handling on the session level I used `URLProtectionSpace` on the `URLCredentialStorage` shared storage and then set that to `Alamofire.Session` configuration

here is an example to set it up (port 443 might be enough)

```swift
fileprivate func registerURLCredential() {

    let storage = URLCredentialStorage.shared

    do {
        let credential: URLCredential = try loadURLCredential("certificate", password: "blablabla")

        let url = URL.API
        let host = url.host ?? ""

        let ports: [Int] = [80, 443, url.port ?? 0]

        for port in ports {

            let space = URLProtectionSpace(
                host: host,
                port: port,
                protocol: url.scheme,
                realm: nil,
                authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
            )

            storage.set(credential, for: space)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}


fileprivate func createSession(_ configurationHandler: ((_ configuration: URLSessionConfiguration) -> Void)? = nil) -> Alamofire.Session {

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default

    registerURLCredential()

    configuration.urlCredentialStorage = .shared

    configurationHandler?(configuration)

    let session = Session(
        configuration: configuration,
        requestQueue: .global(qos: .background),
        serializationQueue: .global(qos: .background)
    )

    return session
}
```

A simple use for that would like:

```swift
let sesstion = createSession({ configuration in

    configuration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1
})
```

Comment: Currently I use hashes and certificate pinning is done. I need to figure how to replace it !

Comment: can you maybe give the link to your question so I can look at it (because the delegate seems to be gone for good)

Comment: I haven't raised any question yet, but I had used exactly before using Alamofire [this approach](https://github.com/nicwise/certificatepinner)

Comment: it seems like you would still be able to generate a `URLCredential` from your approach and then you can use it either in the storage or on a single request

Comment: Hey, I have opened a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194554/alamofire-5-alternative-to-sessiondidreceivechallenge). Please check